# In Rust, how can I create task that runs in its own OS thread?

Tags: multithreading, task, rust

**This question is no longer relevant: Rust green threading is gone.  All tasks correspond to a thread.**

Rust tasks run in a pool of threads managed by the runtime.

I am calling some code via the FFI that will block, and I'll be doing it in a tight loop.

How do I spawn a task on its own OS thread?

The two concerns are that the thread stays scheduled on its thread, and that the work stealing scheduler doesn't bring additional work onto this thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With [std::task::spawn_sched](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/task/fn.spawn_sched.html), you can spawn tasks on a new, single-threaded scheduler that will run on its own OS thread.

```
use std::task::{spawn_sched, SingleThreaded};

do spawn_sched(SingleThreaded) {

    // This runs in its own OS thread

}
```